# Disable a whole activity from user action

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to disable a user interacting with an activity.
To be done when there is an action running (and a spinning progress bar in the title bar)

EDIT: As it seems I was not clear enough I meant to say: while I already have a spinning progress bar, the user is still able to push any button on the activity, I want to disable the user from being able to do that while the task is running. I do not want to however disable each item on the screen one by one.

Thanks, Jason

Comment: Do you want to visibly disable all views, or do you just want them to not respond (=not very intuitive for the user)? Or do you want to show a ProgressDialog on top of your activity?

Comment: Ok, I might have been a little unclear, I meant I already have a spinning dialog but I do not want the user to push more buttons while its working, (IE- disable all items in the activity - but I do not want to do this one by one )

Answer (score 155, accepted):

In order to block user touch events, use:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

To get touch events back, use:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

EDIT:
If you want to add a feature of disable and greyed out display, you need to add in your xml layout file a linear layout that fills the parent. Set its background to #B0000000 and its visibilty to Gone. Than programicly set its visibility to Visible.

Comment: If this does what it sounds like it does, then it suffers from the problem that the user will not see the UI as "Disabled" (Grayed out)

Comment: Ok, I have a solution for greying out the screen. Ill post it later

Comment: Does anyone knows what WindowManager is? Thought I could import it, but eclipse does not propose it to me, so I guess I should get it from another way...

Comment: Don't forget that this will only prevent touch events, so the user will still be able to interact through other input methods, such as a hard keyboard

Comment: This is working like charm... very nice solution... thanx

Comment: this will also disable the toolbar back button.. any way to keep toolbar buttons clickable?

Comment: This does NOT work for translucent activities. In that case, a tap will be made on the content, which is present in the background activity.

Answer (score 11):

If you need to disable event processing for a period of time (for instance, while you run an animation, show a waiting dialog), you can override the activity's dispatch functions.

To disable touch/clicks on any buttons, add these members/functions to your activity:

```
protected boolean enabled = true;

public void enable(boolean b) {
    enabled = b;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return enabled ? 
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev) : 
        true;        
}
```

Then just call `enable(true/false)`  when you need to disable and enable the activity's normal event handling.

Comment: with a few tweaks to invert the boolean, this can be expressed more succinctly as `return disabled || super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);`

Comment: @gMale The return value of the method can indeed be condensed, but there is no need to invert the boolean. The following does the trick: `!enabled || super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)`. Android Studio will suggest that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask with ProgressDialog bundled.

1. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
2. [Progress Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

another useful example:

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using a custom method - which I did not want to do:

```
public static void setViewGroupEnabled(ViewGroup view, boolean enabled)
    {
        int childern = view.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i< childern ; i++)
        {
            View child = view.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup)
            {
                setViewGroupEnabled((ViewGroup) child, enabled);
            }
            child.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
        view.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
```

*If anyone finds a better way I'd like to hear about it! Thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an full screen blank image with a null click handler at the end on the XML layout.

Create a transparent PNG file in the drawables folder.

Add a full screen ImageView at the end of the XML layout referencing the image:

```
...
 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_mask"
     android:id="@+id/imgMask"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
 android:visibility="gone"
     android:onClick="doNothingClick"
 />
```

Add the null click hander for the image to capture user touches:

```
public void doNothingClick(View v){
    // do nothing with the click
}
```

Add the code to disable the user touches:

```
private void StopTouches(int duration){
    findViewById(R.id.imgMask).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            findViewById(R.id.imgMask).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, duration);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use an Image and you don't have to implement an OnClick method.

Answer (score 0):

The code of Uriel Frankel (accepted response), works good, but in my case works after my request it's done :(. I want to block before it happend. Some one knows what is wrong in my code (I'm beginning in this..)

(this is a fragment)

```
   login_login_btn.setOnClickListener {

    if (validateInputs()){
        showSpinner()
        thread {
            doLogin()
        }
    } else {
        validationError("Validation Error","Checkout your inputs. Common errors: \npassword (at least 8 characters)")
    }

}
```

}

## Function after OnViewCreated

```
fun showSpinner(){
    activity?.window?.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
    spinner.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Thank you (Y)

Answer (score -2):

SpinningProgress in the title bar:

```
//onCreate(): 
activity.requestWindowFeature(FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

//and then: 
activity.setProgressBarIndeterminate(boolean indeterminate)
```

both in [Activity class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestWindowFeature%28int%29)

Another option is using Progress Dialog (you might want to set cancelable to false on it).