# How to disable all input controls in an activity in android?

Tags: android

I want to Disable all input controls (eg: TextEdit, Spinners) on click of a button.

Eg: When user enters a value in text field and clicks on Submit button, I would want to disable all input controls and hide keyboard.

An overlay view on top of activity can be added to prevent user from touching screen, but this is not an option since I want to disable all input components and hide input controls.

Comment: to total hide the widget simple do this editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Is this what you refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280608/disable-a-whole-activity-from-user-action

Answer (score 6):

Iterate the container layout view and treat the views depending what widget they're instances of. For example if you wanted to hide all `Button` and disable all `EditText`:

```
for(int i=0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = layout.childAt(i);
    if (v instanceof Button) {
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Or View.INVISIBLE to keep its bounds
    }else
    if (v instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText)v).setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Of course if you wan to add other properties such as making it not clickable or whatever you'd just add them in the correspondent if from the previous code.

Then to [hide the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

A cleaner way of doing this (if you know the ids of the views) is to store them in `int[]` and the loop over that instead of getting al children views from the layout, but as far as the result goes, they're pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take the case of TextView. Then do as follows :

```
textView.setClickable(false);
textView.setFocusable(false);
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

This would disable the TextView. Similarly for the others as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `editText.setEnabled(false);`

Just set `setEnabled(false);` for all controls inside button click.

```
 buttonOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             editText.setEnabled(false);
             spinner.setEnabled(false);

                           .......

                       // here you can disable all InputControls.
        }
    });
```