# Disable touch event for a sibling in a layout

Tags: android, kotlin, touch

I've been trying to disable touch event for a fragment and app bar, but it's not working.

I used view.isEnabled, isClickable and set to false, to disable touch event.

```
    fun disableClickWhenFabExpanded() {
        fragment_content.isClickable = false
    }

    fun enableClickWhenFabCollapsed() {
        fragment_content.isClickable = true
    }
```

I don't know how to use `onInterceptTouchEvent()` on a fragment or view.

I've been trying this way.

`fragment_content.onInterceptTouchEvent()`and no idea what is MotionEvent.could anyone please help me?

Comment: if you want to stop whole screen view clicks try this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10721034/19491703)

Comment: No, that's not my requirement. I have recycler views and bottom navigation bar in home, I want to disable to touch and scroll to recycler view.

Comment: try this to disable scrolling of [recycler view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34060065/19491703)

Comment: sure, I'll try that